# Update values if value1==row1, else not

Tags: php, mysql, json, if-statement

So i want to:

- Look if the phone number that comes in equals to a phone number in the database. If it does, than it must keep the phone number the same value, only update : longitude, latitude & timestamp.
- If the phone number equals null. Don't put any of the values in my
  database. No records at all.
- If the phone number is not in the database, also do nothing. Repeat
  it just like the value is null.

the phone number that i get from input is called **phonenumber**. and the row is called **id**

Here's my code:

```
 <?php



$db = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=dbname;charset=UTF-8', 'user', 'pass',   array(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false, PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION));

if (isset($_REQUEST['data'])){
$data = json_decode($_REQUEST['data']);
$stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT `id` FROM `locatie` where `phonenumber`=:id");
$stmt->execute(array(':phonenumber' => $data->id));
$row_count = $stmt->rowCount();
if($row_count && ($data->phonenumber != '')){
    $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE `locatie` SET `longitude`=:longitude,  `latitude`=:latitude, `timestamp`=:timestamp WHERE `phonenumber`=:id");
    $stmt->execute(array(':longitude' => $data->longitude,':latitude' => $data- >latitude,':timestamp' => $data->timestamp,':phonenumber' => $data->id));
 }
}

?>
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: If the given answers don't provide enough info, use the comments to ask for more feedback, don't just post a new question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your prepare has :id, but the execute params has :phone_number. These need to match.

Edit: actually, you can just do a simple update - if the phone number doesn't exist, then it won't change. One query, instead of two.

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE `locatie` SET `longitude`=:longitude,  `latitude`=:latitude, `timestamp`=:timestamp WHERE `id`=:id AND `phonenumber`=:phonenumber"); 
$stmt->execute(array(':longitude' => $data->longitude,':latitude' => $data- >latitude,':timestamp' => $data->timestamp,':id' => $data->id,':phonenumber' => $data->phonenumber));
```

Comment: Ok i see that, i changed that also, but it doesn't update...

Comment: See the edit - You're getting your IDs and phonnumbers muddled up, but you can do it all in one simple query, instead of the two.

Comment: Somewhere in your 2nd line of code is a syntaxisfault. can's seem to find it. Do you see it?

Comment: Ok i found the syntax error, but it's still not working